# Create CloudSolrClient using solr endpoint

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

Can I create a cloudsolrclient without using zookeeper? 
i dont want to add dependencies on zookeeper and directly talk to solrcloud.

this is my current code.. here endpoint is that of zookeeper. I tried giving solr url but it throws exception saying 
"Couldn't initialize a HttpClusterStateProvider (is/are the Solr server(s) is/are down"

`CloudSolrClient.Builder builder = new Builder(Arrays.asList(endpoint)); return builder.build();`

UPDATE :

used HttpSolrClient to create a client and was successfull. But not able to do any operations with it like listing all collections or create a collection. im using

`List<String> collections = CollectionAdminRequest.listCollections(client);`

is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use Zookeeper, don't create a `CloudSolrClient`, but use a regular `HttpSolrClient` or `LBHttpSolrClient` instead.

The Solr node you're connecting to will route the request internally to the host that has the data that you're requesting (i.e. it'll do the job that your CloudSolrClient would do for you).

The gain by using `CloudSolrClient` is that it'll connect directly to the node hosting your collection, instead of having to go through a potentially non-hosting client and thus get your answer faster without an additional request inside your Solr cluster.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried HttpSolrClient .. and yes i was able to make a client connection. but im not able to do any operations on it like get list of collections or add a new collection.

I am using
List<String> collections = CollectionAdminRequest.listCollections(client);

is this right or am i wrong.

Comment: So what's the error in that case? The CollectionAdminRequest should only be a straight forward http request to the server in the background as far as I can tell.